# Android application development questions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

Question 1: I am new to android app development, in the screen displaying all the available data in database, I want to also provide filters. Preferably something like what Amazon does in thier app or any online shopping app. I have put some sceenshots below, if anyone could guide me how to achieve it would be really helpful.

[image]

when u click on the filter option in above screen, you get something like below :
[image]

or

[image]

Question 2: I want to provide some buttons to the user, which he can use to navigate. There are 12 buttons totally, But these 12 shouldnt be visible all the time. They should be visible only based on the data the user selects. Is this achievable ? If yoes could you please guide.

Question 3: Is it possible to provide two options to the user and based on what user chooses a pie chart would be shown for the data in database. In both these cases X and Y attributes are different. Is this doable? I was thinking of making use of polymorphism. Does that work in Android ??

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for somthing like [Chips](https://material.io/components/chips#types).

[image]

Here's the [MaterialComponents doc](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) to further info.

Comment: But  how can I create collapsable or overlay like the apps I have shown.